# k3sup install older kubectl version v1.24.3

Tags: k3s, postgres-operator, k3sup

I'm using crunchydata/postgres-operator for my k3s based setup however I have started getting error as below due to latest version on kubectl:

```
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=debug msg="debug flag set to true" file="cmd/postgres-operator/main.go:68" func=main.main version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="metrics server is starting to listen" addr=":8080" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/log/deleg.go:130" func="log.(*DelegatingLogger).Info" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="starting controller runtime manager and will wait for signal to exit" file="cmd/postgres-operator/main.go:89" func=main.main version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="upgrade checking enabled" file="cmd/postgres-operator/main.go:94" func=main.main version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="starting metrics server" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/manager/internal.go:385" func="manager.(*controllerManager).serveMetrics.func2" path=/metrics version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="{\"pgo_versions\":[{\"tag\":\"v5.1.0\"},{\"tag\":\"v5.0.5\"},{\"tag\":\"v5.0.4\"},{\"tag\":\"v5.0.3\"},{\"tag\":\"v5.0.2\"},{\"tag\":\"v5.0.1\"},{\"tag\":\"v5.0.0\"}]}" X-Crunchy-Client-Metadata="{\"deployment_id\":\"4d3c5b1b-a13b-46a9-b07d-59dd0fa0205b\",\"kubernetes_env\":\"v1.25.3+k3s1\",\"pgo_clusters_total\":0,\"pgo_version\":\"5.2.0-0\",\"is_open_shift\":false}" file="internal/upgradecheck/http.go:181" func=upgradecheck.CheckForUpgradesScheduler version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:40Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:41Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:41Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:41Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:41Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:41Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:41Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:41Z" level=info msg="Starting EventSource" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:165" func="controller.(*Controller).Start.func1" reconciler group=postgres-operator.crunchydata.com reconciler kind=PostgresCluster source="kind source: /, Kind=" version=5.2.0-0
time="2022-10-28T20:49:42Z" level=error msg="if kind is a CRD, it should be installed before calling Start" error="no matches for kind \"CronJob\" in version \"batch/v1beta1\"" file="sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.8.3/pkg/log/deleg.go:144" func="log.(*DelegatingLogger).Error" kind=CronJob.batch version=5.2.0-0
panic: no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1beta1"

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.assertNoError(...)
        github.com/crunchydata/postgres-operator/cmd/postgres-operator/main.go:41
main.main()
        github.com/crunchydata/postgres-operator/cmd/postgres-operator/main.go:105 +0x570
```

What is the correct way to to resolve this? I tried helm chart provided at: https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator-examples but still no success.

Thanks

Comment: On my k3sup cluster (today), api version of the cronjob is batch/v1. The current latest code of the postgres controller seems to refer to this version. From the error that you posted the operator code refers old cronjob api version "batch/v1beta1" . The commit https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator/commit/446000b6d1e7927606b2ab0b2570f0470d88ddab#diff-91c58fff7c043e42bd5b0db11541911c9f1f52cf65d0c42b206f5287dcb81253 is where the change of version seems to have hapenned. It is possible that the container image being referenced in helm chart you used is based on the older code commit.

Comment: And if what I mentioned above is the case then you can try modifying the value of the container image to use the latest commit tag

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue by setting up old version on Kubernetes version. I'm installing cluster using `k3sup install` so I just added version as part of the command like `k3sup install --k3s-channel v1.24`